# Is it possible to use named parameters in Resource Bundle messages

Tags: java, resourcebundle

Messages of resource bundle will look like
`ORDER_CANCELLED=Order with order id {0} is cancelled.`

But I want to use like
`ORDER_CANCELLED=Order with order id {order.id} is cancelled.`
Where I will pass my Order POJO object to format the message.

Whether Java supports this or Is there any framework which will support this way of placeholders.

Comment: That doesn't have much to do with resource bundles. All they do is associate keys with values for locales. What you're looking for is a templating system, like Velocity or FreeMarker.